# Accessing text from input elements inside a table

Tags: ruby, input, watir

I need get the values (stored inside a **input** element locate in the cells from a table) based in a text. 
How can I do this?
Here is my code:

```
   recordTable = @browser.div(:id => "gridtable").table(:id,'lastgrid')
   puts "Table: #{recordTable}"
   recordTable.rows.each do |row|
       row.cells.each do |cell|
            if(cell.input.text.include?("Paid"))
              puts "TRUE"
            else
              puts "FALSE"
            end                
       end
   end
```

The result is always false, but the text I'm looking for is on the table.

Comment: On a single cell, how do you access this input element? e.g. `cell.text`, `cell.input`?

Comment: @konsolebox I change my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your input element is a text field type:

```
<input type="text" value="text user sees" />
```

Text fields do not text. The text that you see in the text field is actually its value attribute. In other words, you want to check the value attribute instead.

```
cell.input.text
#=> ""

cell.input.value
#=> "text user sees"
```